# Checking if text field is empty

Tags: swift, xcode7

I am attempting to check if a text field is empty but am getting an error of "Type (Bool, Bool, Bool) does not conform protocol 'Boolean Type' "

```
 if(userEmail == "", userPassword == "", userRepeatPassword == "") {


        alertMessage("All fields are required")
        return

    }
```

I am using xcode 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
if(userEmail == "" || userPassword == "" || userRepeatPassword == "") 
{
                //Do Something
}
```

(or)

```
if(userEmail == "" && userPassword == "" && userRepeatPassword == "") 
{
                //Do Something
}
```

Comment: I get a Thread1: Breakpoint 1.1 on the ' if(userEmail == "" || userPassword == "" || userRepeatPassword == "") 
{
                //Do Something
}' what can I do to fix that?

Comment: Use this 'if(userEmail.text == "" || userPassword.text == "" || userRepeatPassword.text == "") { //Do Something }' (or) if you develop swift 2.0 then use this 'if(userEmail.text! == "" || userPassword.text! == "" || userRepeatPassword.text! == "") { //Do Something }'

Answer (score 0):

Your should have used `&&` as this:

```
let userEmail = "William"
let userPassword = "Totti"
let  userRepeatPassword = "Italy"


if(userEmail == "" && userPassword == "" &&  userRepeatPassword == "") {

    print("okay")

}
```

However, there is another way to do it and it is:

```
if(userEmail.isEmpty && userPassword.isEmpty && userRepeatPassword.isEmpty){
    print("okay")
}
```

Also another way is to check the number of characters like this:

```
if(userEmail.characters.count == 0 && userPassword.characters.count == 0 && userRepeatPassword.characters.count == 0){
    print("okay")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (userEmail?.isEmpty || userConfirmEmail?.isEmpty || userPassword?.isEmpty || userConfirmPassword?.isEmpty){

        alertMessage("All fields are required!");
        return;
    }
```

Use this method

Comment: Not a method on UITextField

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to check if a textfield is empty or not:

For Example:

```
if let userEmail = UserEmail.text, !userEmail.isEmpty,
let userPassword = UserPassword.text, !userPassword.isEmpty,
let userRepeatPassword = UserRepeatPassword.text, !userRepeatPassword.isEmpty { ... }
```

If all conditions are true then all variables are unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

After Swift 3.0, better to use the early binding statements, to make the code more clear.

```
guard !(userEmail.isEmpty)! && !(userPassword.isEmpty)! && !(userRepeatPassword.isEmpty)! else {
      return
}
```

// Do something if the fields contain text